# Calling method in other thread QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt, task

Is possible call method in background thread in same class? Using C++/QT without c++11.
Or repeatedly everly 5 seconds run foo2.

Example

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
     void foo(...)
     {
        // in another thread run foo2
        foo2;
     }
  .
  .
  .
  protected:
     void foo2(...){}

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to run some function in a separate thread you can use `QtConcurrent::run` (i use it with `QFutureWatcher`). To run it every 5 or so seconds, use `QElapsedTimer` class

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::foo2, ...foo2 arguments);
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#run or check it here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=QtConcurrent%3A%3Arun

or you can subclass QThread, reimplement run() with the stuff you want to happen in your thread, and then create an instance of your thread and call start() on it.